# Nuxt / Vue query object returns old query after changing it

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, nuxt.js

Given is this nuxt link:

```
<nuxt-link :to="generateCategoryLink($store.state.locale, category.id)" exact :class="{active: isCategoryActive(category.id)}">

// Calls this method to get the link
generateCategoryLink(locale, categoryID) {
  let query = this.$nuxt.$route.query;

  if (this.isCategoryActive(categoryID)) {
    query.categories = this.getQueriedCategories(categoryID);
  } else {
    query.categories = this.getQueriedCategories() + (this.getQueriedCategories() ? "," : "") + categoryID;
  }

  return {path: '/' + locale + '/projects/1', query};
}
```

If I use this code the method always returns a link with the old params. Changing this to:

```
return {path: '/' + locale + '/projects/1', query: { categories: query.categories}};
```

works but since I want to include all other old params (only modify query.categories) that's not an option.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
return {path: '/' + locale + '/projects/1', query: { ...query, categories: query.categories}};
```

Comment: Yes, this solution is working for changing the categories but how I completly remove query.categories then? If I set categories to null, it leaves `&categories` in the uri